# basic MSI installer created using VS requires Administrator

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer

There is similar questions on SO such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157365/how-can-i-create-a-windows-installer-msi-that-does-not-require-admin-access) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73305/how-do-we-create-an-installer-than-doesnt-require-administrator-permissions) however both suggest ClickOnce which I don't (can't) use.

I have started a new Setup project (`InstallAllUsers`=false) and have specified the`Application Folder` to be [LocalAppDataFolder][ProductName]

which at install time points to

C:\Users\nonadmin\AppData\Local\Setup1\

When running the installer on Windows 7 as a non-admin I get this:[image]

From my perspective it appears all the MSI does is copy the one text file to C:\Users\nonadmin\AppData\Local\Setup1\, *something that could be done manually without this popup showing*

The error message says something about 'unknown publisher' - does this occur for any msi/exe that simply runs? (even if it does nothing)

**How can I avoid this dialog (a la ClickOnce) for non-admin users?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid a consent prompt, you need to mark the package as "UAC compliant." (See "Guidelines for Packages" in the MSI SDK.) It looks like Visual Studio deployment projects don't support that bit so you'd have to modify the package in a post-build script (or use a different tool, like [Wix](http://wix.codeplex.com/) that supports it directly).

Any package or executable that isn't Authenticode signed shows up as "Unknown publisher."

Comment: Bob do you know the field to modify post-build? I'm already using a post-build script to make RemovePreviousVersions do what its supposed to do

Comment: "Guidelines for Packages" in the MSI SDK says: "Omit Bit 3 from the value of the Word Count Summary Property to indicate that the package can be required to be elevated. Do not include this bit unless elevated privileges are not required to install this package."

Comment: I use the following command to update `RemovePreviousVersions` in a vbs script: `UPDATE InstallExecuteSequence SET Sequence=1450 WHERE Action='RemoveExistingProducts'` - after much googling I couldnt find any information about how to do the same for the `Word Count Summary` property. The best I found was http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesfi/archive/2007/05/02/making-an-msi-that-doesn-t-need-a-uac-lua-prompt.aspx which mentions the Package/@InstallPrivileges attribute. Do you have any more info that could help do this via vbs?

Comment: The Windows SDK comes with the wisuminf.vbs script to update summary information properties, but you'll have to query the property, turn on bit 3, and then set the property. Package/@InstallPrivileges is a WiX attribute; WiX supports the UAC compliant bit directly. (.vdproj projects are very limited.)

Comment: Thanks, got it working by running `cscript $(ProjectDir)..\WiSumInf.vbs $(BuiltOuputPath) Words=10` Before running this Words=2 (ie `Source is compressed` is set)