# Visual Studio Setup Project: Run the msi installer without administrator rights

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, setup-project

I created an installer with Visual Studio Setup Project and now I have a problem.
To run the installer i always need admin rights, but i want to run the installer silently without admin rights.

My Default Installlocation is:[LocalAppDataFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]

Comment: The whole point of admin rights is to prevent the thing you are trying to do.  If the user is an administrator, or the feature is turned off, then you can install your application, otherwise, the user will be prompted.

Comment: @Neil Here in the video it seems to be possible. yes, only one application should be installed for one user, for that you don't need any admin rights?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fehVTLNQorQ&t=310s

Comment: Maybe there is something in your Wix definition that requires admin permission?

Comment: This will lead to some defects in the security model of the system. What you're really looking for is permission to [elevate rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator).
In addition, you can also use [ClickOnce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73305/how-do-we-create-an-installer-than-doesnt-require-administrator-permissions) to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you correctly set [ALLUSERS and MSIINSTALLPERUSER properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/allusers). These control the installation context (per user or per machine) for your package.

It is not enough to just change the install path to a per user location.